# A criterion for purity

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, ac.commutative-algebra, moduli-spaces, coherent-sheaves, quasi-coherent-modules

I have started reading the book "The Geometry of Moduli Spaces of Sheaves" by Huybrechts and Lehn. This is a statement in this book at [page no.3](https://books.google.com/books?id=_mYV1q0RVzIC&pg=PA3) the last line.

"$E$
is pure if and only if all associated points of $E$ have the same dimension." Definition for associated points of a sheaf is as follows:

$Ass(E)=\{x∈X|m_x∈AssE_x\}$.

1. How to prove this statement specially the converse part that if all associated points have the same dimension, then $E$ is pure?
2. Can anyone suggest me some reference in this regard?

Comment: I thought that was the definition of "pure".  What is the definition of pure in Huybrechts and Lehn?  Also, please be advised that there is at least one other definition of pure in local commutative algebra: the definition that is used in SGA 2.

Comment: @JasonStarr The definition for pure is as follows: $E $ is pure of dimension d if $dim(F) = d$ for all non-trivial coherent subsheaves $F \subset E$

Comment: For (1), assume that all associated primes of $E$ have the same dimension $d$, then $\dim E=d$. If $0\neq F\subset E$, then on the one hand, we have $\dim F\leq d$. But the associated primes of $F$ are also associated primes of $E$ and thus we have $\dim F\geq d$.

Comment: @JasonStarr ,@Mohan How do we relate torsion free sheaf and pure sheaf?                                                                                                            Pure sheaf implies torsion free sheaf. What is the proof of this statement?

Comment: This is a cross-post of https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2099967/33855